# How do I get an Indy HTTP Server in Delphi to receive connections in an iOS application?

Tags: ios, delphi, indy10, httpserver, delphi-xe4

I am writing a multi-platform application that is a sort of 'proxy', designed to field HTTP requests and pass some of them to a remote server and respond to others directly. So it acts as both an HTTP client and an HTTP server.

I have been using the Indy 10 components in both Delphi and Lazarus, and they work well on desktop platforms. I have ported the project successfully to Windows, Linux, and MacOS using Lazarus. Now I am attempting to do the same to iOS, using Delphi XE4. I am currently running the project in the iOS Simulator on a Mac running OSX 10.8.2; later I will be targeting an iPad device.

But I'm finding that I can't get the TIdHTTPServer component to create a connection to an incoming request on iOS. I bind the server to an IP address and port and activate it; this starts the listener thread. But when I try to send a GET request to the server it raises the exception EIdIPVersionUnsupported, with the message "The requested IPVersion / Address family is not supported." This error happens whether I try to route the GET request from within the application itself, or externally from a browser running on another machine.

I normally bind the HTTP Server to the localhost IP address, as the proxy is intended to run as a background process fielding requests from the browser running in the foreground. For the external browser test, I bound it instead to the Mac's own IP address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The majority of Indy components, including `TIdHTTPServer`, work **exactly the same way** in iOS as they do on other platforms.  The only thing that changed in Indy to support iOS was implementing the low-level socket API function calls (via the `TIdStackVCLPosix` class), and updating Indy's internal coding to support the new Embarcadero mobile compilers (ARC, etc).

`TIdHTTPServer` should work on iOS, as long as it has permissions to open a TCP/IP listening socket.  An `EIdIPVersionUnsupported` exception means that a low-level socket API call was attempted using an IP version that `TIdStackVCLPosix` does not support for that particular API call.  All of the `TIdStackVCLPosix` methods support IPv4 and IPv6.  So, without seeing the actual stack trace leading up to the exception, I can only guess that maybe Posix's `accept()` function is reporting that the connected client is using a socket address type other than IPv4 or IPv6.

With that said, I did just fix a minor bug in `TIdStackVCLPosix.Accept()` where it was not initializing the size of its address storage before calling POSIX's `accept()` function, so that may or may not be a contributing factor.  Grab the latest Indy 10 SVN release (which has other bug fixes that did not make it into the XE4 release) and try again.